# Xamarin.Forms application properties not removing keys

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In one page, I remove a key from my application properties:

```
async void SaveAndClose()
{
    Application.Current.Properties.Remove(FOO_KEY);
    await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();    

    foreach (var key in Application.Current.Properties.Keys;)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Key in properties: {key}"); //FOO_KEY is missing, good!
    }
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Everything seems to be working properly. The key is gone and only the other stuff remains. However, if I put the following in the page that comes up following the `Navigation.PopModalAsync`:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    foreach (var key in Application.Current.Properties.Keys;)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Key in properties: {key}"); //FOO_KEY is back!
    }
}
```

All of a sudden the key has returned, along with its value! What is causing the dictionary to unsave itself? As the docs show `Application.Properties` to be "just" a IDictionary, there aren't any gotchas listed. What's going on?

I'm using Xamarin 4.12.3.83.

Comment: is it on iOS? Have you tried using Xamarin Essentials Preferences instead?

Comment: @Prateek: I've only tested on android so far.

Comment: I use `Properties[key] = null;` to delete them. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Xamarin Essentials Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Application Properties will be deleted only if you uninstall the app

or if you still want to delete then, you may have to set autobackup false on android and not link iPhone to iCloud. For preferences also you need to set this as false in order to delete it forever.

[Reference](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96513/application-current-properties-how-do-you-clear-out-the-keys-values)